# best polynomial approximations to $f$ vanish at $0$ imply $f$ is an odd function

Tags: polynomials, approximation, approximation-theory, orthogonal-polynomials, even-and-odd-functions

It is known that if $f\in C[-1, 1]$ is odd/even, then the best polynomial approximation (in $L^{\infty}$ norm) of degree $n$, denoted by $p_n$, must also be odd/even. This has been asked on MSE before.

In particular, if $f\in C[-1,1]$ is odd, then all best polynomial approximations $p_n$ vanish at $0$. And I am wondering about the converse claim:

> If all best polynomial approximation $p_n$ to $f\in C[-1,1]$ vanishes
> at $0$, can we say $f$ is odd?

It seems not simple to answer, I am wondering if there is a proof or disproof for it.

If the approximation is in $L^2$ sense, then the zeros of orthogonal polynomials have the interlacing property, so it seems easier to deal with.

Comment: What about the best polynomial approximation to $x^2$?

Comment: @AlkaKadri the best $p_0=\frac{1}{2}$ then due to the equioscillation theorem.